# Apparently missing overload of getline() taking RRef to stream in GCC 4.7.2 and Clang 3.2

Tags: c++, c++11, stream, getline, rvalue-reference

I ran into an unexpected compilation error when trying to use `getline()` with a temporary stream object:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string input = "hello\nworld\nof\ndelimiters";

    string line;
    if (getline(stringstream(input), line)) // ERROR!
    {
        cout << line << endl;
    }
}
```

It looks like no overload of `getline()` exists that accepts an rvalue reference to a stream object. If I change `main()` to use an lvalue, it compiles and runs as expected:

```
int main()
{
    string input = "hello\nworld\nof\ndelimiters";

    string line;
    stringstream ss(inpupt);
    if (getline(ss, line)) // OK
    {
        cout << line << endl;
    }
}
```

So I had a look in the C++11 Standard and I found out (§ 21.4.8.9) that an overload of `getline()` that takes an rvalue reference to a stream object *should* be present.

Am I missing something obvious, or is this a bug? The error occurs both with GCC 4.7.2 and with Clang 3.2. I cannot test this on VC at the moment.

Comment: clang uses the same standard library as gcc by default. You might try using libc++ with clang. libc++ is a more complete implementation of the c++11 standard library than libstdc++ which is used by gcc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I compile on OS X with the following line, it compiles successfully. What version of the libstdc++ or libc++ are you using?

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ foo.cc
```

libstdc++ (and libc++ for that matter) do not yet fully implement the C++ 2011 standard library. This appears to be one of the missing functions from libstdc++.

Sadly, I don't know of any resource that lists exactly what is missing from each implementation.

Comment: I am trying it [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/BIiXX$0), not sure what is the version.

Comment: libstdc++ 4.7.2 (what you're likely using on there) does not implement that method.

Comment: Yes. It should. libstdc++ (gcc's libc++) is not fully implemented yet.

Comment: OK, thank you. Please add this information to your answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Note that most of the iostreams in libstdc++ is missing move operations.

Comment: For further reference you can find the implementation status of libstdc++ [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.200x).