# Why can I not use a temporary ifstream in C++ 11?

Tags: c++, c++11, iostream, rvalue

Why must I declare the named variable `file` in the following code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int const argc, char const * const * const argv) {
        string head1;
        ifstream file {argv[1]};
        getline (file, head1);
        cout << head1 << endl;
}
```

If I try

```
getline (ifstream(argv[1]), head1)
```

I get `no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::ifstream {aka std::basic_ifstream<char>}’ to ‘std::basic_istream<char>&’` or similar (gcc 4.6, 4.8 or clang 3.3).

I don't understand, because according to [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/?kw=getline) there is a definition

```
istream& getline (istream&& is, string& str);
```

and I don't understand why that conversion can not be done (temporary can be used as rvalue, and `istream` is a base class of `ifstream`).

Comment: Perhaps your standard library implementation does not provide that overload yet. You're also missing an include for `string`.

Comment: It looks like we're missing that overload in GCC - I'd better add it!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14574486/apparently-missing-overload-of-getline-taking-rref-to-stream-in-gcc-4-7-2-and

Comment: @JonathanWakely it would probably help if people filed bug reports, although I have to admit I have a couple of issues I have seen on SO I have not gotten around to filing either.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour, yes indeed, if someone had reported it in January '13 when the duplicate was answered I could have fixed it before GCC 4.8.0 was released :-(